# sum of even numbers in lists in list python

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

How do I find the even number from multiples of list and add them all together?
For example:
I have this function to start this

```
def sum_even_lol(lol):
```

and

```
sum_even_lol([[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]])
```

so it would be 2+6+4(calculation done by the code)
should return 12.

Answer (score 4):

you can convert the list of lists to a flat list, then filter only the even numbers and add those in a generator expression like this:

```
def sum_even_lol(lol):
    return sum(n for l in lol for n in l if not n % 2)
```

or if you find nested generators less readable than ideal, you can reduce by using `sum()` - but you have to remember to provide an empty array as the initial value:

```
    return sum(n for n in sum(lol, []) if not n % 2)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as expected. Cannot add lists using sum() in python

Comment: @Alfie right, different implementation of `sum()` from the native addition.. nested generator should do the job then

Comment: @Alfie found a way. nested generators probably perform better than combining, but I find the first approach very unreadable

Answer (score 1):

You can find the evens by simple list comprehension :

```
evens = [item for i in lol for item in i if item%2==0]
```

The to return sum :

```
return sum(evens)
```

In all, the function definition would look something like this:

```
def sum_even_lol (lol):
    evens = [item for i in lol for item in i if item%2==0]
    return sum(evens)
```

Comment: ah, ok. So I use [item for i in lol for item in i if item%2==0] to get the even numbers from the lists. Thank you for he answer :)

Comment: Please do mark a solution as answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sum(val for v in l for val in v if val % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit unclear on what you're asking exactly, but these ideas might help.

Something like:

```
evens = [element for element in my_list if element%2 == 0]
```

will return a list, `evens`, that has only the even elements from the list `my_list`.

You can also use

```
list_sum = sum([my_list])
```

to easily get the sum of numbers in a list.  I think you should be able to combine these together to do what you want from here!

Comment: Sorry I typed the question on my phone and it has certain limitations to see if I put right thingo in the question.